# Facebook integration in cross-platform mobile apps

Tags: javascript, android, html, facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse for JavaScript, and is working with the ionic framework within the Intel XDK.

I am trying to incorporate social media login, where users are able to signin using facebook.

I generally know how to navigate this but my main concern is the following:
I am using facebook for javascript where it requires a URL, and when that URL is not accessible it doesn't work. Hence, on an iphone or android I cant use facebook yet.

The specific error I get is the following:

```
Warning
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

**What have I done as far?**
I went over the following guide thoroughly:
http://www.benjamin.my/how-to-set-up-facebook-connect-plugin-and-parse-com-in-ionic-phonegap/

It does mention near the end of the guide that

```
You may have to add an iOS setting or Android setting too eventually when you deploy to either platform.
```

and this is the part where I am having issues, and for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set     `<access origin="*" />` in your config.xml so you can access all external domains?

See [the cordova whitelist guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide) for more information on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Could you elaborate on your response? What is the domain name I should set on the facebook app for javascript, and I have a config version for each platform (config.android, config.ios, config.windows), so how should this be added to all. thanks

Comment: You should do it in the main config.xml (in the project folder), so it will be carried to all platforms. You need to whitelist all the URLs your app needs to access, using the asterisk just whitelists all (allows your app to communicate with ANY URL).

Comment: sorry being so newbie, but on the facebook app page, in the site and mobile url, I guess I also need to whitelist the URL as well. How would I do that just typing * is not a valid url. thanks

Comment: It did seems to work only on mobile, but the one issue I am having is that it bypass the login page, and just goes to the following page regardless or not a previous facebook account is on

Comment: @user3907211 - what do you mean by facebook app page; an asterisk is frequently used in programming to define "all".

Comment: @jon220 - Can you rephrase? I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: okay. The access origin does not seem to be the solution. When I load on mobile, the facebook screen doesnt appear.

Comment: yes unfortunately. in fact, on mobile that popup does not even show